# Linux UDP Socket recvmsg with MSG_ERRQUEUE

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

In order to get ICMP errors (e.g dest unreach.) while sending with sendto() on socket X, it is possible to call recvmsg on that socket X with MSG_ERRQUEUE flag. (OS = linux)

```
 recvmsg(X, &msg, MSG_ERRQUEUE);
```

I am binding this socket X with port Y and I am not able to receive the udp packets with Port Y AND the ICMP errors generated by sendto().

Is it possible to receive "normal" udp packets when MSG_ERRQUEUE flag is set ? or with MSG_ERRQUEUE flag can recvmsg() only receive from "error" queue ?

Thanks

Comment: Is this so hard to simply try and see if it is or is not?

Comment: yes I tried and it seems it is not. I just wanted to know whether I am doing something wrong or whether it is not possible per design.